# How to generate a single column output from multiple duplicate columns in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

| ID | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 94 | 94 | NA |
| 2 | 72 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 87 | NA | 87 |
| 4 | NA | 78 | NA |
| 5 | 67 | 67 | 67 |

I would like to generate an output by selecting only one value per row from X1-3 so the output would appear as below:

| ID | X |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 94 |
| 2 | 72 |
| 3 | 87 |
| 4 | 78 |
| 5 | 67 |

I have tried using unite which merges the data but does not remove the NA value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

We could use `coalesce`:

Here we create a new column `X` that contains the first non-NA value from the columns X1, X2, and X3 and then we select column ID and X:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(X = coalesce(X1, X2, X3)) %>% 
  select(ID, X)

  ID  X
1  1 94
2  2 72
3  3 87
4  4 78
5  5 67
```